# windbg 10.0 do not show line numbers

Tags: windows-10, windbg, callstack

When I switched from windows 7 to windows 10 (new SDK of course) I faced this different behavior in WinDBG when showing callstack with command "kc":
Windows 7:

```
KERNELBASE!RaiseException
msvcr120!_CxxThrowException
msvcp120!std::_Xout_of_range
```

Windows 10:

```
00 KERNELBASE!RaiseException
01 msvcr120!_CxxThrowException
02 msvcp120!std::_Xout_of_range
```

How to get rid of line numbers?

```
00 
01 
02
```

which are links like ".frame 0n0;dv /t /v"

Comment: At issue is not your OS update, you updated the SDK.  So got a new version of WinDbg, lots of changes.  Just keep using the older version of WinDbg if you prefer its UI.

Comment: yes, you are correct that the main reason is new SDK, however i prefer using actual SDK for actual windows version.
I assume it could be the way to turn this view changes off

Answer (score 5, accepted):

turn off dml

```
kd> .prefer_dml 0
DML versions of commands off by default
kd> kc

WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
LiveKdD
nt!KiInitialPCR
nt!KeWaitForSingleObject
nt!NtWaitForSingleObject
nt!KiFastCallEntry
ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
kd> .prefer_dml 1
DML versions of commands on by default
kd> kc
 # 
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
00 LiveKdD
01 nt!KiInitialPCR
02 nt!KeWaitForSingleObject
03 nt!NtWaitForSingleObject
04 nt!KiFastCallEntry
05 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
```

Comment: Excellent! That's exactly what I needed